# How to disable GameObject after animation is finished

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have an animation that fades into the menu screen but after the animation ends none of my buttons work. I have figured out that it is because the GameObject that holds the black image that fades to clear is always in the front, blocking me from using any of the buttons. I tried to write a script, that's attached to the game object, that disables the GameObject after it completes the animation, but it isn't working.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animation anim;

    public void SetTrigger()
    {
        this.StartCoroutine(this.PerformAnimRoutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator PerformAnimRoutine()
    {
        var state = anim.PlayQueued("Fade_In", QueueMode.PlayNow, PlayMode.StopSameLayer);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(state.length);

        this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the code or is there an easier way to accomplish this? I am extremely new to unity so I am very stuck.

Answer (score 4):

If all you are doing is fading a sprite to clear and you seem to know about coroutines, I might start by suggesting you do the fade within a coroutine instead.
Have that decrease the alpha by some fraction each frame and when it's `0` disable the object.
That's just if that sounds more fluid, nothing wrong with the animation way.

Doing it with animations though :

I'm not confident that you can disable the object the animation is on in that animation. If it is available on the dope sheet try that. Otherwise we can use state behaviours or animation events.

### Animation Events

These can be used to trigger a function at a certain point of an animation. You can create them similar to keyframes. Here is a link to [Unity's guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) on this topic.

All you'd need to do is create an event and place it at the end of the animation. Then you need to in a script of that object make a public function that simply disables the object. Call that with the event.

### State Behaviours

[State Machine Behaviours](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StateMachineBehaviours.html) allow you to define a script to run on a given animation state. It has many functions to hook onto such as `OnStateEnter` and `OnStateExit`.

You'd want to click on the state that fades in the animator. In the inspector you should be able to click "Add Behaviour". This will create a script that you can open and edit. [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html) is the reference for that class.
From there is should be very simple to disable the object through `OnStateExit`.